# How to retrieve a matched substring where a string matches a list of potential substrings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Long-time user of Stack Overflow though couldn't find a clear answer to this

OBJECTIVE: Next to each Product field I need to find and retrieve a matching Brand which substring is in another worksheet.

-Worksheet 1 (Products) I have a single column with 76,000 rows
 -Worksheet 2  (Brands) I have a single column with 2,000 brands and growing

Sample Data:

**Products**
COLUMN A

- ANGEL BRAND BLACK OLIVES 2KG
- ANMOL SALT TABLE 750GR
- 76,000 others

**Brands**
COLUMN A

- ANTONELLI
- AH
- AHG

So the result should fetch a brand from a  growing list and dynamically place it in the Products Worksheet:

- A1- PRODUCT  B1- BRAND
- A2- ANGEL BRAND BLACK OLIVES 2KG B2- ANGEL
- C2- ANMOL SALT TABLE 750GR   C3- ANMOL

I have searched a number of forums and am convinced that the INDEX MATCH Array is what I need to do, though can't seem to get the syntax... it might be that I need to include a SEARCH in there somewhere.

This was the closest thing I found to what I need though couldn't exactly make it work for me: [How to find if substring exists in a list of strings (and return full value in list if so)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043065/how-to-find-if-substring-exists-in-a-list-of-strings-and-return-full-value-in-l)

Thank you for your patience in my explanation... I'll get better at this!

**UPDATE:** This kinda does what I am after though it takes quite a while to refresh and it's only picking up the first couple of letters as opposed to the entire word:

> =IFERROR(INDEX(BRANDS!A:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(BRANDS!A:A,A2)),,),0)),"No Match Found")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the brand name is always included in the `Products` then, you can try:

> =INDEX(Brands!$A:$A,MATCH(1,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(Brands!$A:$A,A2)),0,1),0))

You enter this formula on B2 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
So for example, you have below set-up:

[image]

It will give you what you want. Take note though that re-calculation may take a while since you are dealing with a lot of data.

Another option would be to do this using macro which you'll need to run every time you open the workbook.

**IMPORTANT:** This will fail though if you have brand names like `BLACK` or `OLIVES` which is also found on the product name.

Comment: An effective result. I found more success in using this Formula
=IFERROR(INDEX(BRANDS!A:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(BRANDS!A:A&" ",A1)),,),0)),"No Match Found")

Comment: Scatch my last answer... it effectively works the same as the answer I had in the original question, the only addition I added to the previous comment is a concatenated space after the search so that it returns a whole word followed by a space. Important to note that this would only return brands with a space following it...
Your suggestion for a VBA macro seems the best option.