# Excel Formula - Match substrings of List to List

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, substring, match

I have two Lists in an excel spreadsheet.

The first list has strings such as

```
1234 blue 6 abc
xyz blue/white 1234
abc yellow 123
```

The other list contains substrings of the first list

```
yellow
blue/white
blue
```

Result

```
1234 blue 6 abc         blue
xyz blue/white 1234     blue/white
abc yellow 123          yellow
```

Now I need some kind of **match formula to assign the correct value from the second list to the first**. The problem, there is no specific pattern to determine where the color substring is positioned. The other problem, the values are not totally unique. As my example above shows, the lookup needs to be in an order (checking for "blue/white" before checking for "blue").

I played around the formulas like `match`, `find` also using `wildcards *` but couldn't come to any result.
A similar question asked here on SO covers the opposite case [How to find if substring exists in a list of strings (and return full value in list if so)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043065/how-to-find-if-substring-exists-in-a-list-of-strings-and-return-full-value-in-l)

Any help is appriciated. A formula would be cool, but using vba is also okay.

Comment: did you try VBA?

Comment: You can use `find()` worksheet function for finding out if a substring (like `blue` or `yellow` is present in a complete string (like `1234 blue 6 abc` or `abc yellow 123`).

Comment: @Error1004 Yes, VBA can solve this issue easily, I was just wondering how a formula solution would look like. I didn't think about the `AGGREGATE` function as user10779473 used it. I can post the VBA code as a seperate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=INDEX(D$7:D$9, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($1:$3)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D$7:D$9, A2)), 1))
```

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21666929)

Comment: In what way does this not answer the question? It specifically provides a solution to *'need some kind of match formula to assign the correct value from the second list to the first'* and the provided image proves the OP's sample data and expected results.

Comment: The benefit of leaving an explanation is that if somebody comes across the answer by a google search at a later date, they are able to understand the logic and can modify the formula to fit their needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with VBA

- List 1 (strings) is in column A
- List 2 (substrings) is in column C

The code basically contains to nested while loops checking whether the substring is inside the string.

```
row_1 = 1
While .Cells(row_1, "A") <> ""
    row_2 = 1
    While .Cells(row_2, "C") <> ""
        color = .Cells(row_2, "C").Value
        If InStr(1, .Cells(row_1, "A"), color, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            .Cells(row_1, "B") = color
        End If       
        row_2 = row_2 + 1
    Wend
    row_1 = row_1 + 1       
Wend
```