# Excel - show if a cell has a substring from a range of cells, showing the substring that match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a substring from a cell if it is contained at a range of strings.

For example, given the column A, D and E, I want to generate the column B

[image]

I searched the internet for a possible solution, but nothing solved this problem.

Examples followed unsuccessfully:

> [How to find if substring exists in a list of strings (and return full value in list if so)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043065/how-to-find-if-substring-exists-in-a-list-of-strings-and-return-full-value-in-l)

Can you help or point to the best way to solve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: What formula did you actually use from the other question and how did it not work?

Answer (score 2):

Using [Cell contains one of many things](https://exceljet.net/formula/range-contains-one-of-many-substrings) as a starting base, I developed this to work for your situation.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:$E$4,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(things,A1)),0)),"")
```

Note this is an array formula, so it must be entered by pressing `**Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Enter**` when exiting edit mode in the cell. Also, things is a named range referring to the range `$D$1:$D$4`

[image]